# How to make Entity Framework cache some objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity

I'm using Entity Framework.

In my database are stored persons and country of their origins. When I'm loading a person object I wan't to know what is the place each person originates. Is there a way to cache list of countries so that there wouldn't be unnecessary requests.

Comment: Bump.  Has anything changed with EF in 5+ years, regarding look-up table caching?  Specifically, has EF integrated a way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As Luhmann has already said my mate Jarek has an excellent sample Caching provider for the Entity Framework. Which he talks about [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx).

However sometimes this approach is overkill, and I suspect that caching countries is a good example where the effort isn't worth it. It maybe better to implement some sort of ad-hoc caching.

If you try to do this the main problem you will run into is that an instance Entity Framework entity can only be attached to one ObjectContext at a time, which means if you are getting concurrent requests (like in a website) you will have problems is you just grab items from the cache and use them blindly.

What you need is a cloning cache, i.e. so when you grab something from the cache it clones them.

I put together a tip that illustrates how to do this [Tip 14 - How to cache Entity Framework Reference Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/04/22/tip-14-caching-entity-framework-reference-data.aspx)

Hope this helps

Alex James

Entity Framework Team Microsoft.

Comment: from the moment you wrote that tip till now, there is a more straightforward way to cache reference data with EF 4.1?

Comment: Good tip Alex, are there better approaches with the new releases of EF?

Comment: Link not available anymore. I tried searching on MSDN site, but no luck yet

Answer (score 8):

You could take a look at Jaroslaw Kowalski's excellent [tracing and caching provider wrappers for Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers).

Comment: Link not available anymore. I tried searching on MSDN site, but no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

I would cache that country list first and assign the appropriate country to each retrieved person. If you decide to also cache persons you should make them depend on the cached countries and invalidate them when you make any update to the countries/country list.