# What are the best practices for writing a DTO layer in an enterprise ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net, database, dto

Are there any open source alternatives that come with backed in caching etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not open source, I'd recommend checking out the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx).

As for caching when using entity framework, you can check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/04/22/tip-14-caching-entity-framework-reference-data.aspx) article.
And there's another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147681/how-to-make-entity-framework-cache-some-objects) that discusses caching as well.

Comment: I'll be honest, I have not used it myself yet (it's on my list of things to learn, but now I'm working on learning jqGrid with MVC :)) but a colleague of mine said good things about it. With any tool like this though, whether it be Entity Framework, Hibernate, etc., there's always the risk that the tool will generate dumb SQL, so that's always something to keep in mind. Entity framework seems to be where MS is going with DTO though, so it's worth checking out.