# how to get maximum speed for autocomplete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery autocomplete with a textbox which gets its data from the database(SQLserver) every 400ms.

Can I use EF for getting a faster fetch time from the database (lets say the entity fetches data every 1 hour and then I select from it every 400ms) intead of selecting straight from the database?

Comment: Maybe try some caching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147681/how-to-make-entity-framework-cache-some-objects

Comment: it's quite alot of data and caching is not really an option

Comment: I've been working with EF before, and if it's speed you want, EF is **not** what you're looking for.